# Linear Diophantine equation modulo $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a way to find all solutions $(x,y)$ to the equation: $a x + b y = c\pmod n$ for fixed integers $a,b,c$ and $n$?

Regards,
Leon

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence

Comment: Thanks for the link! As far as I can see it discusses the case ax = b (mod n) and not ax + by = c (mod n). Maybe the two are related but I do not immediately see how.

Comment: I admit the relation is very thin which is required to check the solvability.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, lab bhattacharjee! I understand your proof now, but why doesn't it work for this simple example: 15x + 10y = -137 (mod 16). One solution to this equation is (x,y) = (1,4), because 15 + 40 = 55 = -137 (mod 16). The gcd of (15, 10) is g = 5 and using your notation it follows that C = c / g = -137 / 5 which is not an integer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Leon It seems you have another account in this site (80212/leon). Please merge them from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge)

Comment: @f.nasim: Hmm, I've never created an account with this site. I always post as a guest. The link that you sent me seems to be relevant only for users that have an account.

Answer (score 1):

So, $ax+by=c+d\cdot n$ where $d$ is any integer

Now, if $(a,b)=g$ does nor divide  $(c,d\cdot n),$ for any $d$ there will be no solution.

If $g$ divides $(c,d\cdot n)$  let $\frac aA=\frac bB=\frac cC=\frac {d\cdot n}D=g$

So, we $Ax+By=C+D$ where $(A,B)=1$

Using [Bézout's Lemma](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma), we can find integers $u,v$ such that $Au+Bv=1$

So, we have $Ax+By=(Au+Bv)(C+D)$

$\implies A\{x-u(C+D)\}=B\{v(C+D)-y\}$

$\implies \frac{B\{v(C+D)-y\}}A=x-u(C+D)$ which is an integer

$\implies  A$ divides $B\{v(C+D)-y\}$

$\implies  A$ divides $\{v(C+D)-y\}$ as $(A,B)=1$

$\implies  v(C+D)-y=A\cdot m$ where $m$ is any integer

$\iff y=v(C+D)-A\cdot m$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, lab bhattacharjee! Just some clarification: 1) By g = (a,b) I assume you mean that g is the GCD of (a,b)? 2) When you say that g must divide (c, dn) do you mean that g must divide both c and dn? If so, then consider this example: 3x + 3y = -8 (mod 16). Then g = gcd(3,3) = 3 and c + dn = -8 + 16d . g=3 does not divide c=-8 and so g=3 does not divide (-8, 16d) for any d. Yet (x,y) = (0,8) is a solution since 24 = -8 (mod 16). Or do you mean that g must divide (c + dn) for some d in order for the equation to have a solution?

Comment: Finally, a small clarification on my own question: I am actually interested in finding the number of unique solutions to ax + by = c (mod n) (if they exist) rather then the actual solutions. Thanks for your help! L.

Comment: @Leon, $(a,b)=$gcd $(a,b)$